# Ошибка с интерполяцией

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте,
В проекте таких записей у меня очень много

`AppState.AlertOD("Ошибка", $"Ошибка загрузки Guarantee.\n{obj.Error.Message}", ownwindow);`

И во всех местах где написано так, показывает ошибку.
Проект мне предал один человек а у него все работает.

Так как я начинающий не могу понять в чём проблема.
Везде где знак доллара пишет:

```
Ошибка  553 В качестве оператора могут использоваться только выражения 
присваивания, вызова, инкремента, декремента, ожидания и создания нового 
объекта     `c:\users\user\desktop\project\od\dialogskr\guarantee.xaml.cs   497 55  OD`
```

Comment: интерполяция в c# версии 6 и выше, у вас какая?

Comment: У меня 4.5.1 - версия

Comment: framework 4.5.1, скорее всего ваша версия будет c#5

Comment: Попробую поставить. Спасибо!!!

Comment: Visual Studio какой версии?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Нужна как минимум 2015

Comment: Спасибо вы были правы @Ruslan_K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Т.к. вы используете `Visual Studio 2013`, где по дефолту идет компилятор `C# 5.0`, вам следует либо поставить новую `Visual Studio`, либо обновить компилятор.

Обновить компилятор можно с помощью `nuget package`:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/

Как верно заметил @Андрей, этим вы обновляете только компилятор, но `IntelliSense` в `Visual Studio` по-прежднему считает, что вы используете `C# 5.0` и, как следствие, не понимает синтаксиса `C# 6.0` и подчеркивает их как ошибки.

Comment: Только в студии всё равно будет всё красненьким подчеркнуто (вроде), хотя запускаться будет нормально. Поэтому лучше использовать свежую студию 2015 или (что лучше) 2017

Answer (score 1):

Нужна либо `Visual Studio 2015` и выше, либо заменить конструкции

```
 $"Ошибка загрузки Guarantee.\n{obj.Error.Message}"
```

на

```
string.Format("Ошибка загрузки Guarantee.\n{0}", obj.Error.Message)
```