# C# Оператор "return _();"

Tags: c#, linq

Здравствуйте. Требуется включить в проект Visual Studion 2015 Community исходный код из проекта [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ). Попытался запустить sulution и скомпилировать проекты, но проекты даже не загрузились, возникает следующая ошибка:

> C:\Users\rostov.d\Desktop\MoreLINQ-master\MoreLinq\MoreLinq.csproj : error  : пространством имен XML по умолчанию для этого проекта должно быть пространством имен MSBuild XML. Если проект создан в формате MSBuild 2003, добавьте xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" в элемент . Если проект был создан в старом формате 1.0 или 1.2, преобразуйте его в формат MSBuild 2003.  C:\Users\rostov.d\Desktop\MoreLINQ-master\MoreLinq\MoreLinq.csproj

Попытался скопировать только нужные файлы исходного кода в свой проект и скомпилировать. Но Visual Studio ругается на конструкции такого типа:

```
return _(); IEnumerable<T> _()
```

Подозреваю, что это связано с отложенным выполнением Linq запросов. В интернете документации найти не смог. Что это за конструкция `"return"_();` и как скомпилировать такой код под Visual Stuio 2015 Community?
Пример функции с таким return:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Exclude<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int startIndex, int count)
{
    if (sequence == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sequence));
    if (startIndex < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(startIndex));
    if (count < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));

    return _(); IEnumerable<T> _()
    {
        var index = -1;
        var endIndex = startIndex + count;
        using (var iter = sequence.GetEnumerator())
        {
            // yield the first part of the sequence
            while (iter.MoveNext() && ++index < startIndex)
                yield return iter.Current;
            // skip the next part (up to count items)
            while (++index < endIndex && iter.MoveNext())
                continue;
            // yield the remainder of the sequence
            while (iter.MoveNext())
                yield return iter.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: О, прикольно, новые фичи. Наоборот, эта штука новее, чем VS2015. И использована оригинально. Вроде бы должно быть можно поставить какой-то nuget-пакет для поддержки нового шарпа.

Comment: [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) наверное надо установить

Comment: На самом деле это всего лишь вложенный метод, просто форматирование поплыло ) И да, нужен C# 7, а соответственно VS2017

Comment: @Андрей, C#7 можно как-то компилировать в VS2015...

Comment: Наверное - да, надо просто компилятор свежий подключить, думаю...

Comment: @Андрей, nuget-пакет есть для этого, кажется.

Comment: @Андрей https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670066/235242 то же самое касается и C#7 для 15 вижлы

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка с интерполяцией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/670023/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9)

Comment: Как вариант, можно установить чуть более старую версию пакета, как видно по коммитам в Git, поддержка фич C#7 была добавлена сравнительно недавно

Comment: @AGS17, не дубликат, т. к. версия шарпа не та.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Тут используется объявление вложенного метода:

```
IEnumerable<T> _()
```

Это просто метод без параметров, который имеет имя `_` и возвращает `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
return _();
```

А тут возвращается результат вызова этого метода.

Из-за использования `yield return` метод не начнёт выполняться до того, как произойдёт обращение к первому элементу возвращаемой последовательности. Однако, автор хотел, чтобы секция валидации входных данных

```
if (sequence == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sequence));
if (startIndex < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(startIndex));
if (count < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));
```

исполнялась немедленно, поэжтому она должна находиться в методе, не содержащем `yield return`. Т. о. весь метод распадается на два.

И немного ссылок:

- [Когда предусловия не являются предусловиями](//sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2014/11/when-preconditions-are-not-preconditions.html)
- [Итераторы в языке C#. Часть 1](//sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2010/06/c-1.html)
- [Итераторы в языке C#. Часть 2](//sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2010/06/c-2.html)
- [Итераторы в языке C#. Часть 3](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2010/06/c-3.html)
- [ErrorProne.NET. Часть 3](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2016/03/errorpronenet-part-3.html)
- [Новшества C# 7](//habrahabr.ru/post/280978/)
- [Для чего действительно нужны локальные функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/540355/178988)
- [Объясните смысл новшеств C# 7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/539509/178988)

Comment: Добавьте ссылочку, где почитать про это подробнее?

Comment: @Anatol, про итераторы добавил, а вот про новые фичи надо поискать...

Comment: @Anatol, ещё добавил.